# PhpUnit mock included class method

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have two classes, ClassA, ClassB. In ClassA I have Method which call method from ClassB.
For Example:

```
function functionInClassB($state)
{
  if ($state) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function functionInClassA ()
{
  if (functionInClassB(1)) {
    return "Anything";
  }
}
```

Now, I want test functionInClassB with PhpUnit and I dont want functionInClassB ran. I want return value which I want.
Sorry for my English, please help!!!

Comment: I'm confused; you are mentioning classes but your code samples only contain functions (which you cannot mock in PHPUnit). Are the functions in your code members of a class? If so, are you calling them statically or on an instance of that class?

Comment: If you test `functionInClassB()`, you need to run it. Do you mistake to write your question?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think you're referring to stubbing / mocking.

How easy /sensible it is depends. If you want to call functionInClassB *statically* then you're out of luck; static stuff doesn't work well with testing. But if you're calling the method on an *instance* then the following should work:

```
class A {
  protected $instanceOfB;
  public function functionInClassA(B $injectedInstanceOfB) {
    if ($injectedInstanceOfB->functionInClassB(1)) return 'anything';
  }
}

class B {
  public function functionInClassB($state) {
    if ($state) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

class yourPHPUnitTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
  public function testA() {
    $stubOfB = $this->createStub(\B::class);
    // Optionally...
    $stubOfB->method('functionInClassB')->willReturn('something');

    // Thing you want to test
    $a = new A();
    $result = $a->functionInClassA($stubOfB);
    $this->assertEqual('something', $result);
  }
}
```